# IT Security - Where to get started

Tags: networking, security

I was recently offered a position at an IT security company, and may possibly get started in June. I have experience in developing secure applications, configuring secure network infrastructures, setting up secure servers, and managing them. I also have experience with Windows Server 2008 R2. However, I don't yet have hardly any information about the company, what software they use, or even what programming languages/OS they use yet. Where is a good place to get started in IT security, in preparation for my new job in June? What should I know about IT security before getting started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you contact their current IT department and inquire. Since you will likely be having to work with them soon, it will help to get started. Once you find out, I suggest installing their software privately at home, and getting to know it. Then when you arrive, it will be a breeze to get used to it.

You may also want to research the exact topic. So let's say your in network protection - begin researching that and preparing to implement it in a business place.

Comment: +1 Talk to the company you're going to work for, find out what you'll be doing, what you'll be using, and *ask them* what you can do to better prepare yourself for your new job. Not only will this be the best way for you to get ready, but it will send them the message that you care about doing a good job and are willing to work to improve your ability to do good work for them. In other words, bonus points towards your next raise/promotion before your first day!

Comment: Doing so shows great initiative - something i like to think every employer looks for in people